# lxpanel empty except for 2 indicators

Tags: lubuntu, session, lxpanel

There is nothing in the lxpanel, except for 2 indicators: the Wi-Fi indicator and the battery indicator. I don't know what's going on, but I installed this session in Ubuntu via Tasksel.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and add the missing item. Most likely you need "Indicator applet complete".